# Применение border-а

Tags: css

Почему `border-bottom: 2px solid #fff` примененный к блоку `a` отображается на границе блока `li`?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это из-за padding - т.к ссылка - display:block

Answer (score 1):

попробуй так

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Text 1</span></a>
    </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Text 2</span></a>
        </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Text 3</span></a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Вы кстати сами ответили на свой вопрос "Что бы ссылкой было пространство в блоке li. "

Comment: у Вас небольшая ошибка - тег li не закрыли

Comment: и правда, спасибо. поправил

Answer (score 0):

Все из-за того, что у вас тег `a` блочный. И поэтому подчеркивается не текст, а сам блок. Зачем вы вообще сделали его блочным? Удалите эту часть кода и все встанет на свои места.

Comment: Что бы ссылкой было пространство в блоке `li`.
Иначе ссылкой является только сам текст.
А убрав свойство `display:block` бордер вообще перестал отображаться.